# Weird behavior with std::cout in a while loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to append two arrays together. The first array `{0, 1, 2}` when appended to the second array `{3, 4, 5}` should yield `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Let me show you what I have before I move on:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int i = 0;

    int arr1[] = {3, 4, 5}, arr2[] = {0, 1, 2};

    while (i < 3) {
        arr2[3 + i] = arr1[i];
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) std::cout << arr2[i] << std::endl; // print

}
```

I think the way I implemented it is correct. But I find that when I print out the contents of the new array (`arr2`) this is what I get:

```
0
1
2
-1219315227
-1218166796
134514640
```

`0, 1, 2` is the original array, but then `3, 4, 5` has some how been turned into these weird numbers. However, this is somehow fixed with I add an arbitrary `std::cout` statement here in the while loop:

```
...
while (i < 3) {
    std::cout << 5 << '\n'; // just a random #

    arr2[3 + i] = arr1[i];
    i++;
}
...
```

And I print the array once again and it works!:

```
5

0
1
2
3
4
5
```

My question is why is this working when I use a `std::cout` statement inside the while loop as opposed to not doing that, in which case it gives me those numbers?

**EDIT:**

So it turns out what I have here is undefined behavior. With that, my question still stands: why does my code work with an `std::cout` call inside the while loop?

Comment: You're indexing past the second arrays length. I think that's UB?

Comment: @Borgleader, Indeed it is.

Comment: The easy way to do this is with `std::vector`. Just use `insert`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going beyond the bounds of `arr2` here:

```
while (i < 3) {
    arr2[3 + i] = arr1[i];
    i++;
}
```

`arr2` has size 3. What you are doing is undefined behaviour. All observed behaviours are consistent with undefined behaviour.

Comment: My question was why does it print the correct numbers with `std::cout` inside the while loop.

Comment: @David because it is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior.  The shifted around stuff is working out of pure dumb luck, and may fail again at any time due to additional changes.  Fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your second array like so:

```
arr2[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

You are giving it a size of 3. Writing outside those bounds is undefined behavior.

Comment: You're not answering the question. Why does it work when I put a `std::cout` statement inside the while loop.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. The compiler is free to do whatever it wishes.

Comment: @David: Yes it does. Undefined behavior is surprise behavior. We can't tell you why it works because it's an accident. It's not guaranteed to work, it's just luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is **Undefined behavior**:

Problem is that `arr2` is allocated for only 3 items, and you are writing after allocated space:

```
while (i < 3) {
    arr2[3 + i] = arr1[i];
    i++;
}
```

You need to allocate more space for array, or allocate it on heap, so you can use `realloc` function to change its size - or, even better, and more c++-ish - use `std::vector<int>`!